# Compare value in dict with other values

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I'd like to compare all entries in a dict with all other entries – if the values are within a close enough range, I want to merge them under a single key and delete the other key. But I cannot figure out how to iterate through the dict without errors.

An example version of my code (not the real set of values, but you get the idea):

```
things = { 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 22 }

for me in things.iteritems():
    for other in things.iteritems():
        if me == other:
            continue
        if abs(me-other) < 5:
            print 'merge!', me, other
            # merge the two into 'a'
            # delete 'b'
```

I'd hope to then get:

```
>> { 'a': [ 1, 2 ], 'c': 22 }
```

But if I run this code, I get the first two that I want to merge:

```
>> merge! ('a', 1) ('b', 2)
```

Then the same one in reverse (which I want to have merged already):

```
>> duplicate! ('b', 2) ('a', 1)
```

If I use `del things['b']` I get an error that I'm trying to modify the dict while iterating. I see lots of "how to remove items from a dict" questions, and lots about comparing two separate dicts, but not this particular problem (as far as I can tell).

**EDIT**
Per feedback in the comments, I realized my example is a little misleading. I want to merge two items if their values are similar enough.

Comment: FWIW, my actual purpose is comparing the perceptual hash of two images, so the code is less semantic than my example above.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? You are essentially iterating over the cartesian product of the items in the dict, i.e. pairs, `(key, value)`

Comment: So, when you compare `me == other` you are comparing `tuple` objects, `(key1, value1) == (key2, value2)`

Comment: Pls provide the exact output you want. Which element should be deleted? the starting ones or the ending ones?

Comment: @KaushikNP that is a good question, but there *are no starting ones, or ending ones*. `dict` objects are inherently unordered.

Comment: Oh woops @juanpa.arrivillaga . My fault. Keep forgetting.

Comment: Am I understanding something wrong or are all your examples self referencing?

Comment: Sorry everyone – my example wasn't as clear as it could have been. Updated now. Essentially: I want to compare all values with all others and merge if they are close enough.

Comment: @JeffThompson well, if all you wanted to do is *merge* then use the grouping idiom in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, to do this in linear time (but requiring extra space) use an intermediate `dict` to group the *keys* by value:

```
>>> things = { 'fruit': 'tomato', 'vegetable': 'tomato', 'grain': 'wheat' }
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouper = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in things.iteritems():
...     grouper[v].append(k)
...
>>> grouper
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'tomato': ['vegetable', 'fruit'], 'wheat': ['grain']})
```

Then, you simply take the first item from your list of values (that used to be keys), as the new key:

```
>>> {v[0]:k for k, v in grouper.iteritems()}
{'vegetable': 'tomato', 'grain': 'wheat'}
```

Note, dictionaries are inherently unordered, so if order is important, you should have been using an `OrderedDict` from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your result will depend on the direction of the traversal. Since you are bucketing data depending on distance (in the metric sense), either the right neighbor or the left neighbor can claim the data point.

Comment: That's true, though in this case I don't care which value gets merged into which key.